# Overflow-Y scroll not working

Tags: xcode, swift

I got the constraints just how I want it in iPhone 5 it fits in one screen and in iPhone 4 it overflows to the bottom which is fine. But why can't I scroll down?

iPhone 5:

[image]

iPhone 4:

[image]

As you can see in iPhone 4 the bottom is not visible and all I want is to be able to scroll there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without seeing how you are settings the constraints on the Interface Builder, I think that doing like below could help you to solve your problems:

1. Possibly you are not embeding all views in a scrollView properly. If so, select all subviews, choose Editor from menu -> Embed In -> View to wrap everything in a container. (UIView). After that select the container then choose Editor -> Embed in -> Scroll view
2. Set up all necessary constraints between subviews and the container ( As you did before making the view in the shared screenshot)
3. Set up all margins between the container and the containing scrollView to be zero ( top/ left/ right/ bottom = 0). Ensure that the scrollView fit the screen by having zero margin constraints as well.
4. Last but not least, set a width constraint of the container to any number you want (e.g.: 320 /375), then make an IBOutlet for this constraint
5. On viewDidLoad, set the constant of the container's width constraint you made in step 4 to current screen width.

That's all.

Comment: Thanks man! I had figured it out before using step 1 and setting my constraints but this looks like a better way to do it!

Comment: Glad to hear that you made it!

Comment: Yea my only problem now is in iphone 4 (the only scrollable view) that when I scroll all the way down and I try to scroll more the image somehow starts to enlarge. Very weird.

Comment: Create another question, give me your code I think I can help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563282/scrolling-after-bottom-of-scrollview-enlarges-image/32563599?noredirect=1#comment52982523_32563599 problem is fixed thanks anyway!