# Scrolling after bottom of scrollview enlarges image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have this scrollview:

[image]

This is the bottom of it:
[image]

But when I try to scroll even further than the bottom, the image starts to enlarge somehow like this:

[image]

Why does this happen? I don't want anything to happen when scrolling more than the bottom.

Comment: Your `UIImageView` variable's name where the images take place is  `imageView` ?

Comment: Are using Auto layout? If yes than there may be a case that one of the constraint of either `UIImageView` or `UIScrollView` was not properly defined.

Comment: The outlets name is `weatherImageView` and yes I am using auto layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround using which you can resolve this issue. Just uncheck all the bounce properties of scrollview to disable scrollview scrolling beyond the content.

Comment: Love to help others :-)